# Show an image from web in DataGridView cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a binding list and source linked to my DataGridView.

When I add an item to my binding list, I want to show that image (from the web) in the cell. Is this possible?

This is what I have so far, I am able to load the image from web, but I don't know how to show it in the DataGridView row in the first column:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static BindingList<VideoInfo> searchResults = new BindingList<VideoInfo>();
    BindingSource bindingSearchResults = new BindingSource()
    {
        DataSource = searchResults
    };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resultGrid.DataSource = bindingSearchResults;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchResults.Add(new VideoInfo()
        {
            Thumbnail = DownloadImage("http://i.ytimg.com/vi/uJbDSPRqX0o/mqdefault.jpg"),
            Title = "Man's Best Friend - Cyanide & Happiness Shorts",
            Url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJbDSPRqX0o "
        });
    }

    private Image DownloadImage(string imageUrl)
    {

        try
        {
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
            return Image.FromStream(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        }
        catch { }
        return new Bitmap(1, 1);
    }
}

public struct VideoInfo
{
    public Image Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine here, at least if the button click is hooked up.

You may want to add a line or two to adapt the height of the thumbnail cells:

```
int maxWidth = -1;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in resultGrid.Rows)
{
    Size imgSize = ((Image)row.Cells[0].FormattedValue).Size;
    row.Height = imgSize.Height;
    if (imgSize.Width > maxWidth) maxWidth = imgSize.Width;
    resultGrid.Columns[0].Width = maxWidth;
}
```

Of course you can do that in advance if you know that all thumbnails will have a fixed size.